# In R, how can I make a function with dynamic column assignments? I want to replace a row values in a column whose name I pass to the f'n

Tags: r, function, replace

In dataframe `df` and column `a`, I would like to replace all `is.na` and all `a=2` `<- 0` for all rows.

This has been achieved simply with the following: `df[is.na(df$a) | df$a==2, "a"] <- 0`

I will be doing this over and over again over different columns (`b`, `c`, `d`, etc) so I just wanted to see if I could build a function. I will simply use the function over and over again. That way, if I need to change which values or which output, it will be a simple task.

Here is a small example. First the dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame(
  a=sample(c(0,1,2), 10, replace=TRUE)
  )
```

Now some missing values:

```
df[sample(nrow(df), 3, FALSE), "a"] <- NA
```

Finally, the action to replace [which I already mentioned]:

```
df[is.na(df$a) | df$a==2, "a"] <- 0
```

I have tried the following function:

```
f.na<-function(df,col) df[is.na(df[,col]) | df[,col]==2, col]<-0
f.na(df, "a")
```

I feel like it should work but I cannot figure out why it doesn't. I get:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , col) : undefined columns selected

I know that I cannot use the `$` sign so I tried using this `[]` format after reading some things online. I had used an `apply` type of function but then later I could not use the results in a dataframe. So I resorted to this way. I guess I can just iterate over and over for each column I need to modify but I thought the function solution would be nice.

Can you suggest anything I should try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error. However, your function call will not have the desired effect because modifications to `df` inside your `f.na` function do not have global scope. Instead, one solution is to have your function return the modified object, like this:

```
set.seed(37337)
df<-data.frame(
  a=sample(c(0,1,2), 10, replace=TRUE)
)
df[sample(nrow(df), 3, FALSE), "a"] <- NA
f.na<-function(df,col) {
  df[is.na(df[,col]) | df[,col]==2, col] <- 0
  return(df)
}
(df.new <- f.na(df, "a"))
df[is.na(df$a) | df$a==2, "a"] <- 0
print(df)
```

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you for the explanation about the scope of arguments as well. This helps, lockedoff.

Answer (score 1):

To access a column in a data frame (or element of a list) by a name stored in another variable you want to use doubled brackets `[[]]` instead of the single ones.

However, for what you are doing you may want to look into macros instead, see the article on macros in [this issue of Rnews](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2001-3.pdf) and also the `defmacro` function in the `gtools` package.

Comment: Thanks Greg, that's also useful.